# MY CPUs At 100% If I Run Anything Even after OS Re-install

Tags: 20.04, dell, cpu-load

It's a Dell Inspiron 2016 I5 quad core CPU w/ 8 gigs of ram. I don't think it should be obsolete already. The CPUs are always at 100 esp with any kind of website with a lot going on like FB or youtube. I just re-installed the OS for the 3rd time in a few weeks trying to resolve this problem. Unbuntu 20.04. It came with Windows 10, but had the same issue, and took 20 minutes to boot. It worked better with 18.04 for a few years.

Is this a hardware issue? Is it just time to get a new PC? OR is there soemthing I can do?

I'm getting a gaming PC after this, I'm done with laptops, nothing but headaches and you can't upgrade them if the hardware is faulty or obsolete.

[image]

Comment: What processes are using the CPU? Include the output of `top` in your question.

Comment: If you want to find out with GUI, go the the `Processes` tab next to `Resources` in System Monitor, and arrange the processes in decreasing order of CPU cycles. The process consuming most CPU cycles will be shown at the top.

Comment: Many websites abuse your CPUs and bandwidth. As @vanadium says, top is good to find out what processes are consuming top CPU time. Then kill your browser tabs one by one to see who are the culprits.

Comment: Could be a kworker process.

Comment: In Chrome/Chromium, try going into the settings, under advanced > system, disable hardware acceleration. Restart the browser and see if the behavior continues.